# How to remove duplicates from json and then inserting into mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json

I want to remove duplicates from my JSON data and then put data into MySQL
can anyone tell how to remove duplicate(before inserting into MySQL)

```
import json
import pymysql
con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db="bulk")
cursor=con.cursor()
file_name=["prime (1).json","prime (2).json", "prime (3).json","prime (4).json","prime (5).json","prime (6).json","prime (7).json","prime (8).json","prime (9).json","prime.json"]
for file_name in file_name:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        file_data=json.load(f)
        for item in file_data:
            href=item.get("href")
            thumbnail=item.get("thumbnail")
            text=item.get("text")
            imdbRating=item.get("imdbRating")
            year=item.get("year")
            imdbUrl=item.get("imdbUrl")
            wikiUrl=item.get("wikiUrl")
            cursor.execute('insert into bulk_data ( href,thumbnail,text,imdbRating,year,imdbUrl,wikiUrl) values("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")',(href,thumbnail,text,imdbRating,year,imdbUrl,wikiUrl))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove duplicates in python -- rather use the database for that. First, define what you mean by a duplicate -- is it where the `thumbnail` column is the same? If so, [mark the relevant column in the database as unque](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-an-existing-field-unique-in-mysql) before you insert data into it. Now use python's exception handling, wrap it in a transaction and you'll be sorted:

```
import json
import pymysql
con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db="bulk")
cursor=con.cursor()
file_name=["prime (1).json","prime (2).json", "prime (3).json","prime (4).json","prime (5).json","prime (6).json","prime (7).json","prime (8).json","prime (9).json","prime.json"]
for file_name in file_name:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        file_data=json.load(f)
        for item in file_data:
            href=item.get("href")
            thumbnail=item.get("thumbnail")
            text=item.get("text")
            imdbRating=item.get("imdbRating")
            year=item.get("year")
            imdbUrl=item.get("imdbUrl")
            wikiUrl=item.get("wikiUrl")
            try:
                cursor.execute('insert into bulk_data ( href,thumbnail,text,imdbRating,year,imdbUrl,wikiUrl) values("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")',(href,thumbnail,text,imdbRating,year,imdbUrl,wikiUrl))
                con.commit()
            except:
                con.rollback()            

con.close()
```

Comment: you mean i should define the column unique in MySQL?

Comment: I'd suggest that